# How to get a more specific result from a JSON object in volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to get a more specific result than what I am currently getting. Here is my code:

```
// Request a string response from the provided URL.
    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject city = response.getJSONObject("city  ");
                        mTextView.setText("" + city.toString());
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what I get in return :
[image]

More specifically, I'm just trying to get the city name when the JSON value is returned. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the image you posted:
`response.getJSONObject("city").getString("name");`

You have to request a specific field from the JSONObject that way.
`city.toString()` is doing what its supposed to do.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        String cityName = response.getJSONObject("city").getString("name");
        mTextView.setText(city);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. In fact, I couldn't use .getString("name") because that's not valid. I had to use .getJSONObject("name") just to get it to compile and it still doesn't deliver the desired result.

Comment: What do you mean? `getString()` is a perfectly valid call on `JSONObject` as documented here.
http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Comment: Have you tried it? I get an error that says "incompatible types. Required JSONObject found String

Comment: I've rephrased my answer. `getString()` returns a `String`.